# Capistrano intervals between restarts of the servers to ensure service continuity

Tags: passenger, ruby-on-rails-5, continuous-deployment, capistrano3, hotfix

I know the best practice for pushing changes to production is to have sets of servers A and B, to have A serve the website for the client, to push the update on B and then switch A<->B to ensure the continuity of services. But this feel kinda hard to implmeent with Capistrano (?)

I currently have a pool of autoscaled servers on the Amazon cloud. Using capistrano, my deploy command will deploy the update on all the servers, and restart them all at the same time. During the period when passenger restarts itself, there is a downtime on my production server (and restarting can take up to 10 sec so it's a problem).

In order to avoid this, I'd like to restart my servers one at a time, and to wait x seconds before restarting the next server (I don't mind if I have 2 different versions of the code online, the target scenario I have in mind, is deploying a small hotfix)

Is there a way to override Capistrano restart task so as to wait some time before starting the command on the next server ?

Comment: I think you can pretty much reuse this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810339/capistrano-sequential-restarts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually using Capistrano-Passenger for restarting my server, and I just noticed there's a `set :passenger_restart_wait, 5` command which seems to do that already !

[From the gem readme](https://github.com/capistrano/passenger)

Answer (score 1):

This is built in:

```
on :all, in: :sequence, wait: 15 do
  # Your restart task
end
```